# Finding the min values in a data frame column for each day

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe (df) that looks like:

```
            Value
03/03/2014      3
03/03/2014      3
03/03/2014      6
03/03/2014      4
03/03/2014      5
03/03/2014      3
03/03/2014      5
03/03/2014      8
03/03/2014      7
04/03/2014      6
04/03/2014      9
04/03/2014      2
04/03/2014      3
04/03/2014     10
04/03/2014      6
04/03/2014      7
04/03/2014      5
04/03/2014      7
05/03/2014      1
05/03/2014      9
05/03/2014      5
05/03/2014      9
05/03/2014      2
05/03/2014      9
05/03/2014      6
05/03/2014      8
05/03/2014      1
06/03/2014      9
06/03/2014     10
06/03/2014      9
06/03/2014      6
06/03/2014      8
06/03/2014      5
06/03/2014     10
06/03/2014      5
06/03/2014     10
07/03/2014      8
07/03/2014      7
07/03/2014      4
07/03/2014      5
07/03/2014      9
07/03/2014      2
07/03/2014      3
07/03/2014      2
07/03/2014      4
```

I would like to add a new column `DayMin` which contains the minimum value for each day in column Value and would look like:

```
            Value   DayMin
03/03/2014      3        3
03/03/2014      3        3
03/03/2014      6        3
03/03/2014      4        3
03/03/2014      5        3
03/03/2014      3        3
03/03/2014      5        3
03/03/2014      8        3
03/03/2014      7        2
04/03/2014      6        2
04/03/2014      9        2
04/03/2014      2        2
04/03/2014      3        2
04/03/2014     10        2
04/03/2014      6        2
04/03/2014      7        2
04/03/2014      5        2
04/03/2014      7        2
05/03/2014      1        1
05/03/2014      9        1
05/03/2014      5        1
05/03/2014      9        1
05/03/2014      2        1
05/03/2014      9        1
05/03/2014      6        1
05/03/2014      8        1
05/03/2014      1        1
06/03/2014      9        5
06/03/2014     10        5
06/03/2014      9        5
06/03/2014      6        5
06/03/2014      8        5
06/03/2014      5        5
06/03/2014     10        5
06/03/2014      5        5
06/03/2014     10        5
07/03/2014      8        2
07/03/2014      7        2
07/03/2014      4        2
07/03/2014      5        2
07/03/2014      9        2
07/03/2014      2        2
07/03/2014      3        2
07/03/2014      2        2
07/03/2014      4        2
```

I can see I can use `df['DayMin']= df['Value'].min()` to get the column global minimum.  But I can't see how to do this for each day and return it to the df.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby().transform`:

```
df['DayMin'] = df.groupby(level=0)['Value'].transform('min')
```